# Using AWS Serverless Application Repository

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

It is mentioned that AWS Serverless Application Repository is in preview mode, I want to use it for publishing my live users. So my questions are: 1. Is preview mode means AWS Serverless Application Repository is in beta mode? 2. As it is in preview mode, How much it's support is reliable?

Answer (score 2):

Preview Mode means that you need to apply to use the service. Amazon will ask you for your intended use case and why you want to use the service in advance of general availability. I do not recommend using preview services with live customers, only for internal testing. There is no real answer if its support is reliable - that is one of the purposes of preview mode.

Comment: Thanks John, My requirement is my serveless package shuold get installed on Client AWS environment, can you please suggest me the better way instead of AWS serverless repository.